# notify-send to other user by crontab

Tags: bash, cron, notification, su

I have script what is running by crontab but as su, at some point is possible that it will send notify by notify-send but I want to this to specific user (login is in $2, but only one will be logged in at the same time)

I tried below lines but no works ;(

`export DISPLAY=:0.0`

`eval "export $(egrep -z DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS /proc/$(pgrep -u $LOGNAME gnome-session)/environ)";`

```
username=$2
pid=$(pgrep -u $username nautilus)
dbus=$(grep -z DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS /proc/$pid/environ | sed 's/DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=//' )
export DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=$dbus
```

Thank you for help in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this and it works cool:

```
DISPLAY=:0 sudo -u $2 notify-send "$path not found!
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding `head -n 1` works because now there are three lines of data from `pgrep -u $LOGNAME gnome-session`.

`eval "export $(egrep -z DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS /proc/$(pgrep -u $LOGNAME gnome-session | head -n 1)/environ)";`

I am using it in [my script for monitoring the ZFS and mdamd](https://github.com/vstoykovbg/mdamd-zfs-notify-send).